# how do I catch multiple error types

Tags: python, try-catch

I want to print an attribute from an object that may not exist yet or may be initialized to None.

I'm wrapping it in a try/except.  However, the two exceptions I want to catch are `NameError` when trying to access a variable that doesn't exist, or an `AttributeError` when trying to access an attribute of an object that doesn't exist.

#### Question

How do I catch both exceptions at once?

#### What I've done

```
try:
    print myobject.a
except NameError:
    pass
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Comment: You mean `except (AttributeError, NameError):`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So simple.  Sometimes the simplest of things seem so difficult for me to find or figure out.

Comment: You can also use `except (AttributeError, NameError) as e:` if you want to do something with the exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use parentheses:

```
try:
    print myobject.a
except (NameError, AttributeError):
    pass
```